# Button background transparency using Win32 and Visual Styles

Tags: c, winapi, button, transparency, comctl32

***Edit:** If anyone's tried this in win32 before, am I going in the right direction by using DrawThemeBackground()?*

I'v recently enabled Visual Styles using a manifest for version 6 of ComCtl32.dll.  Example of Visual Styles in Win32: [Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773187(VS.85).aspx)

The buttons look great, but I can't figure out how to make the background around the buttons transparent.  Please see example image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?2bdeff33ba.jpg

My main window background color is set to dark grey with:

```
a.hbrBackground = GetStockObject(DKGRAY_BRUSH);
```

The common controls are initialized with:

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX stylesStruct;
stylesStruct.dwSize = sizeof(stylesStruct);
stylesStruct.dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&stylesStruct);
```

And I create the button windows with:

```
j = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"hello",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 100, 100,
    100, 100, h, 0, hInst, 0);
```

Buttons look fine over a white background, but the border becomes visible over anything else. Is it possible to make the border around buttons transparent?

Comment: It sounds like you still didn't get the answer you were looking for here, even though you accepted it. I [provided an answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483599/transparent-background-of-xp-themed-control/4551951#4551951) that was asked more recently; see if that's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`?

I think you can set it in the resource editor in Visual Studio, if you're using that.

Comment: Thanks, that does help (the boarder is thinner). But there's still a thin black border around the button.  Do you know if there's a way to fill that with the background color?