# Transparent background of xp-themed control

Tags: c, winapi, themes

I have a few window controls drawn on a bitmap as well as on colored background on a dialog-box. Would there be some possible way to make the window controls' background transparent? Currently they show the default colored background of a dialog-box.

Example - I tried to paste a solid blue bitmap and the two button controls have the noticeable default colored-rectangle background.

[image: Dialog window containing two UI-buttons in the middle: 'OK' and 'Cancel'. Though the buttons are a default off-white, most of the inside area of the dialog-box has a shocking bright blue background.]

Comment: Erm, if you see the dialog box background then they are already transparent.  If you want to see the bitmap then you'll have to draw it in the dialog's WM_ERASEBKGND message handler.

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot of what you're seeing? I'm not exactly clear on what you *are* seeing and what you *want* to see. And what language are you working in?

Comment: I've also tried with a pattern brush to fill the background of button but that is not true for all the buttons that are outside or over another bitmap.

Answer (score 7):

This is easily solved by providing Windows with a handle to whichever brush you want it to use to paint your button's background. You do this whenever you receive the **[`WM_CTLCOLORBTN` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761849.aspx)** in the button's parent window's message handler.

I mocked up a little demo application that compares two different buttons side-by-side. Both are standard Win32 `BUTTON` controls, but the one on the left handles the `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` message and specifies a brush with the same color as the window background. You can see the difference immediately—the light gray (or, more precisely, the default color for 3D controls, `COLOR_3DFACE`) fringes around the button's rectangle are gone and the button looks much better against the custom background color:

[image: Transparent Buttons Sample in Windows Vista]

The effect also works in Windows XP with visual themes enabled—here's a screenshot of the same app:

[image: Transparent Buttons Sample in Windows XP]

And the code that I used to create the above effect is almost ridiculously simple. Add this to your app's main window procedure (`MainWndProc`), as described above. You don't need to touch your buttons.

```
HBRUSH hButtonBackColor = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch(msg)
   {
      case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
      {
         if (!hButtonBackColor)
         {
            // Create the brush, if it hasn't already been created.
            // (You can use any type of brush here; this is just an example.)
            hButtonBackColor = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DDKSHADOW);
         }
         return (LRESULT)hButtonBackColor;
      }

      // ...
   }
}
```

However, make sure that the brush you specify represents exactly the same color as your window's background color—a transparent brush may not work properly. Similarly, for a patterned brush (does anyone use those anymore?), the [brush's origin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183396.aspx) will need to be set to match the background.

**Always make sure that you release any brushes that you create by calling [`DeleteObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183539.aspx)!!** In C++, you would do this by making a `CBrush` object (or equivalent) a member of your dialog class so that it would be automatically destroyed. In C, you'd need to handle the `WM_NCDESTROY` message and delete the brush manually.

Also note that you **do not** need to specify the [`BS_OWNERDRAW` style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951.aspx) in order for this trick to work. The example above uses two standard button controls, created using only the following window style flags: `WS_CHILD`, `WS_VISIBLE`, and `BS_PUSHBUTTON`.

Of course, if your design is any more complex than the above example (e.g., your buttons overlap multiple backgrounds), you'll probably have to go the owner-draw route, instead. I just think that's overkill for a task as simple as the one you appear to be describing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can make a truly transparent background, but my solution may help you anyway. I've always solved it by using the WM_CTLCOLORBTN message in the main window's procedure.
Let's assume that we have a `switch`, in which we process the messages received by the main window.

```
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
    return (LRESULT)hBgColor;
break;
```

where `hBgColor` is an `HBRUSH`, for example:

```
HBRUSH hBgColor=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));
```

As I said before, this doesn't really make the control's background transparent - it just sets it to the specified color.
**EDIT:** I'm sorry, I've done a mistake before. I've written `LPARAM` instead of `LRESULT`. Now it's correct.